# HttpClient.SendAsync throwing System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException when sending large JSON files (>1 MB)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have an external web-service working over HTTP protocol in RESTful manner. It can accept pretty large JSON documents (from 1MB to 20-30MBs), does some transformations and returns another large JSON document, which has size equal or not less than accepted JSON document's size.

It works perfertly fine while testing via Postman.

I use ASP.NET Core 2.2 and trying to do the same request with `HttpClient`. My application accepts data, creates the same JSON document and sends it to the external web-service.

Here the code I use:

```
public async Task<TResponse> MakeRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request)
{
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(TRequest));

        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = HttpMethod.Post, Content = content };

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseString);
            return (responseObject != null) ? responseObject : throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

**It works fine** when the JSON document's size is small - it works for 4KB document, for 20KB document, for 200KB document, but starting from about 800KB document it throws `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` and inner `System.IOException` with only message **The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.**.

It fails on line `var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);`.

I tried to create HttpClient object manually or via injecting it via `IServiceCollection` - the same behavior.

```
services.AddHttpClient<IExternalWebServiceProxy, ExternalWebServiceProxy>()
            .ConfigureHttpClient(x =>
            {
                x.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1000 * 100;
            });
```

Is there any idea what can cause the problem?

Update - exception.ToString() message:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at XXX.XXX.XXX.Internals.NCANodeProxy.MakeRequest[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request) in D:\Sources\XXX\XXX\XXX.XXX.Core\Internals\ExternalNodeProxy.cs:line 36
   at XXX.XXX.XXX.Services.CryptoService.SignFileDocument(SignFileCommand command) in D:\Sources\XXX\XXX\XXX.XXX.Core\Services\CryptoService.cs:line 134
```

Comment: An exception that says what? Is it a 400? A 500? Does it contain an error message?

Comment: If the *server* returned an invalid response, it doesn't seem it can handle large JSON files. Then again, are you sure you didn't get an error page instead of an actual response? Try using Fiddler or another debugging proxy to see what was *actually* received from the server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, exception says "The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response."

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, server returns a valid response while testing with Postman.

Comment: An HttpException includes the status code, assuming the server returned one. What is the exception's status code? Post the *full exception text*, not just the message. You can get the full text with `Exception.ToString()`. If the server redirected you to an error page though, only Fiddler will show it

Comment: It's not *Postman* that fails. Postman probably didn't send the same request your code does either.  Use Fiddler to see what's actually being sent and returned